# sql query to calculate sum and add sum from previous rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is my table T1

```
  dat_dt      credit     debit
 --------     ------     -----
22-02-2019      10         5
25-02-2019      30         60
10-03-2019      50         40
13-03-2019      100        10
```

I want to generate the following output

```
max_date    cr_sum    progressive credit  dr_sum progressive debit 
--------    ------    ------------------  ------  -----------------
25-02-2019    40            40              65           65
13-03-2019    150           190             50           115
```

I want to calculate sum of credit and debit in each month, the progressive credit is the column which is sum of credit in that month added to progressive credit of previous month. same for progressive debit. max_date is the maximum date in each month. Is there any simple method to get this output other than using loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
with t1(  dat_dt, credit, debit) as
(
 select date'2019-02-22',10,  5 from dual union all
 select date'2019-02-25',30, 60 from dual union all
 select date'2019-03-10',50, 40 from dual union all
 select date'2019-03-13',100,10 from dual    
)
select max(dat_dt) as "max date",
       sum(credit) as "cr sum",
       sum(sum(credit)) over ( order by to_char(dat_dt,'yyyymm') ) as "progressive credit", 
       sum(debit) as "dr sum",
       sum(sum(debit))  over ( order by to_char(dat_dt,'yyyymm') ) as "progressive debit"
  from t1
 group by to_char(dat_dt,'yyyymm')
 order by to_char(dat_dt,'yyyymm');
```

with aggregation by year-month combination.

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/ACAK31402)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select max(dat_date) as max_date,sum(credit) as cr_sum,
       sum(credit) over(order by EXTRACT(month FROM dat_date),EXTRACT(year FROM dat_date)) as progressive_credit,
       sum(debit) as dr_sum,
       sum(debit) over(order by EXTRACT(month FROM dat_date),EXTRACT(year FROM dat_date)) as progressive_debit
group by EXTRACT(month FROM dat_date),EXTRACT(year FROM dat_date)
```

Comment: I'm not much familiar with over (order by ) query, it seems correct but it shows not a GROUP BY expression.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a cumulative sum, but aggregated by month:

```
select max(dat_dt) as dat_dt,
       sum(credit) as credit,
       sum(sum(credit)) over (order by min(dat_dt)) as running_credit,
       sum(debit) as debit,
       sum(sum(debit)) over (order by min(dat_dt)) as running_debit
from t1
group by to_char(dat_dt, 'YYYY-MM')
order by min(dat_dt);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3610e7a667ab22fcc939cb7b335fcc42) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: it shows an error - group function is nested too deeply

Comment: @Nidheesh . . . The code works fine.  I added a db<>fiddle.  (Actually, I misspelled `dat_dt`, but that is also fixed.)