# Update Query - Sum of previous row x and current row y

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update

I having a table LedgerData and need to update the Balance.

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LedgerData]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Credit] INT,
    [Debit] INT,
    [Balance] INT
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_LedgerData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LedgerData] VALUES (1, 1, 50, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LedgerData] VALUES (2, 1, 0, 25, 0);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LedgerData] VALUES (3, 2, 0, 75, 0);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LedgerData] VALUES (4, 1, 0, 10, 0);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LedgerData] VALUES (5, 2, 5, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LedgerData] VALUES (6, 1, 10, 25, 0);
```

I tried to update the balance column customer wise `ORDER BY [Id] ASC`, but its not updating as expected. Also I explored the [sql query to calculate sum and add sum from previous rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901586/sql-query-to-calculate-sum-and-add-sum-from-previous-rows)

Please assist me to calculate the balance column `Balance = (Previous Row Balance + Credit - Debit)`

Comment: Please add your expected results to your question.

Comment: Just to be clear: `id` is the column that defines the order, right?

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing sums over partial sets of a table into it isn't a good thing to do. Drop the column `balance`. If you need the balance, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally this is something you should be doing *as* you `INSERT` the data, by getting the previous value (and locking the table so that other `INSERT` statements can't occur to avoid races) and then supplying a value for the `Balance`. You can, however, `UPDATE` all the rows with a cumulative `SUM` and an updatable CTE:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           CustomerID,
           Balance,
           0 + SUM(Credit) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) - SUM(Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS NewBalance
    FROM dbo.LedgerData)
UPDATE CTE
SET Balance = NewBalance;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.LedgerData;
```

Alternatively, don't store the aggregate value at all, and use a `VIEW` so that the value can always be calculated (accurately) with the same expression I have used in the CTE. For example:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.LedgerDataCumulative
AS
    SELECT Id,
           CustomerId,
           Credit,
           Debit,
           SUM(Credit) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) - SUM(Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS Balance
    FROM dbo.LedgerData;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The update can be performed with a single window function.

```
with upd_cte as (
    select *, sum([Credit]-[Debit]) over (partition by customerId order by id) sum_over
    from #LedgerData)
update upd_cte
set Balance=sum_over;
```